# Google App Script not firing every time onedit trigger is used

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

Google App script not firing all JavaScript  pop up boxes using on edit trigger. Does not fire when a change is made to the sheet for multiple users. Also only works when it feels like it. I have set the trigger to onEdit(). My code:

```js
function Error() {
  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  
  if (sheet.getName() == "Protocal  Check List 2"){
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); // Same variations.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var active = ss.getActiveCell();
  var getactive = ss.getActiveCell().getDisplayValue();
  var column = ss.getActiveRange().getColumn();
  var row = ss.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var msg = '';
  var section = sheet.getRange('C'+ row);
    
  switch (column) {
    case 9:
        var msg = "error 1";
        break;
    case 10:
        var msg = "Error 2";
        break;
    default: 
        msg = "Error";
        break;
        }
   if(getactive == "TRUE"){
 
  if(column >= 9 && column <= 60
    ){ 
  var result = ui.alert(
      "pika  Says",
      msg,
      ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

  // Process the user's response.
  if (result == ui.Button.YES) {
    // User clicked "Yes".
    window.alert('Task Complete: \n\n' + msg);
    active.setValue('True');
  } else {
    
      var i = 0;
      
      while (i < 1) {
      var result = ui.prompt(
      'Please detail cause of the problem:',
      ui.ButtonSet.OK);

      
      var text = result.getResponseText();
      
      var textcount = text.length;
      
      if(textcount > 0) {
      i++;
      }}
    
    var cell = "H" + row;
      
      var emailAddress = "email@gmail.com";
      var d = new Date();
      var n = d.toDateString();
      var t = d.toTimeString();
      var staffname = ss.getRange(cell).getValues();
      
      var message = "Date: " + n +"\n\nTime: " + t +"\n\nStaff: " + staffname + "\n\nError: " + msg + "\n\nProblem: " + text;
      var subject = msg;
      
      var thedate = n + " / " + t;
      
      ss.getRange('A1').setValue(thedate);
      ss.getRange('B1').setValue(staffname);
      ss.getRange('C1').setValue(msg);
      ss.getRange('D1').setValue(text);
     
      var s1 = ss.getRange('A1:D1'); //assign the range you want to copy

      var s1v = s1.getValues();
      
      var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1mOzdRgKxiP5iB9j7PqUWKKo5oymWuAeQZ1jJ1s6qL9E'); //replace with destination ID

      var ts = tss.getSheetByName('AB Protocal'); //replace with destination Sheet tab name
      
      ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1,4).setValues(s1v); //you will need to define the size of the copied data see getRange()
      
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  
      // User clicked "No" or X in the title bar.
      //ui.alert("The following note has been sent to the Duty Manager: \n\n" + text);
      active.setValue('FALSE');
    
  }}}}
  
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. I need it to run every signal time for users who have access to the sheet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failure of calling Google App Script onEdit function many times in a second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52811408/failure-of-calling-google-app-script-onedit-function-many-times-in-a-second)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> You'll have to
>   assume that onEdit triggers are best-effort, but may not catch all
>   edits done to the spreadsheet.

Bug thread is [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36760530).

Answer (score 0):

To get around the bug as mentioned by [Edward](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51198707/834280) implemente a dumb router.

```js
// create a new file -> router.gs
function routerOnEdit(e) {
   myOnEditHook1(e);
   myOnEditHook2(e);
   myOnEditHook3(e);
}
```

Comment: How exactly does this code work?
Is there a separate routerOnEdit event that is triggered on edit?

Comment: @AlexanderBenjamin You setup the routerOnEdit function to be triggered by the ON_EDIT event, and then any functions that you want to fire on edit you just call inside your routerOnEdit function. it's like a straight one to many passthrough.

Comment: @WiR3D Please explain how this gets around the 'best effort' scenario. This seems like the exact same bug will happen. Sometimes onEdit gets called, sometimes it doesn't.

For me, onEdit doesn't get called the second time, when I make 2 edits in quick succession. I don't see how adding a router function fixes this.

My current trigger is already a custom trigger that point to 'OnEdit', not the default 'onEdit'. So as far as I can tell, our code is the same...

Answer (score 0):

I have submitted an issue, which is the updated version of a long-running 7 year issue. They closed it in 2022, saying the feature is intended. They have now added a feature where onEdit can queue up to 2 trigger events. The issue I'm having is that the second edit still does not trigger. Despite what the documentation says.

> Note: The onEdit() trigger only queues up to 2 trigger events.

View the new issue here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/221703754