# Failure of calling Google App Script onEdit function many times in a second

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have been struggling with a strange behavior of onEdit function of Google Apps Script.

To my understanding, this onEdit event is fired every time a cell is edited. It is no problem when I edit a cell slowly like one cell for every 1 second. All events are fired for sure.

However, when I edit a few cells in a second very quickly, some of them aren't fired. So I want to make sure onEdit event is fired even when I edit cells very quickly. Below are my code, am I missing something?

I have been debugging for this whole day... Please help me out with this issue.

```
function onEdit(e){
  var as = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var r = e.source.getActiveRange();
  var edditRow = r.getRow();
  console.log(edditRow);
  as.getRange(edditRow, 2).setValue('edited');
}
```

Comment: Try `LockService` ?

Comment: I added LockService but it didn't work...

Comment: [Edit] to show 1. modified code 2. Script execution log(view>executions) with relevant  explanations and error logs

Comment: @steve you seem to be right.  I did it slightly different and simply typed a character and return several times in a row quickly.  The cursor advances to the next row and again the next row but seems to skip every other setValue("edited").  {e.range.offset(0,1,1,1).setValue("edited");}

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a known limitation of onEdit.

From a [comment](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36760530#comment4) by Eric Koleda, a Googler, to [Only two onEdit trigger events can be queued at a time in New Sheets](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36760530)

> You'll have to assume that onEdit triggers are best-effort, but may not catch all edits done to the spreadsheet.

Comment: @steve type s l o w l y :)