# How can I make my onEdit code recognize pasted data on multiple cells?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I copied a code from https://www.seerinteractive.com/blog/google-sheets-scripts/ to move rows from one tab to another. I modified the code to trigger it whenever a cell in the specified column was edited. It worked on both manual edit and copy pasted data, but when I tried copy pasting the data on multiple cells in the specified column, it only moves the first cell in the selection and the rest of the cells below doesn't move. Also when I edit the cell too fast, it sometimes doesn't move the row.

I tried using the onChange trigger but I cannot figure out how to make it work.

```
function onEdit() {


  var sheetNameToWatch = "raw";
  var columnNumberToWatch = 16;
  // column A = 1, B = 2, etc…
  var valueToWatch = "1";
  var sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo = "data prep";

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveCell();

  if (sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch && range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch && range.getValue() == valueToWatch) {
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo);
    var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).moveTo(targetRange);
    sheet.clearContents(range.getRow());
 }
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think you can.  onEdit(e) only knows the value of the upper left cell of the range edited.  And onChange only know what type of edit but does not know any of the values.

Comment: See this for information on edit event object https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events

Answer (score 1):

The question has two parts

Regarding getting all the values of a range, use getValues instead of getValue. This will return an array of arrays (2D array).

Regarding the onEdit trigger not being triggered all the time, this is an known limitation of onEdit. It's already reported on the issue tracker an on some questions here.

Related

[Failure of calling Google App Script onEdit function many times in a second](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52811408/1595451)