# How to ensure onEdit functions do not miss-fire

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have a google sheet where the user scans in barcodes of products. I need to record the date and time of when the product is scanned, so have built an onedit script to do just that. However it is not consistently firing.

```
function onEdit(event) { 
var eventRange = event.range;
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
if ( s.getName() == "Dolly Returns") {
if (eventRange.getColumn() == 2) { 
var columnARange = 
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(eventRange.getRow(), 1, 
eventRange.getNumRows(), 1);
var values = columnARange.getValues();
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
values[i][0] = new Date();
}
columnARange.setValues(values);
}
}
}
```

If I begin to edit the cells in Column B (relatively quickly) the code seems to struggle to update Column A for every edit. It does indeed work if you pause a few seconds between each edit, but I'm hoping the code can be improved to ensure it fires 100% of time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failure of calling Google App Script onEdit function many times in a second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52811408/failure-of-calling-google-app-script-onedit-function-many-times-in-a-second)

Comment: Can I ask you about your situation? For example, in the following cases, there is a workaround. 1. Values are put to the empty cells of the column "B". In this case, you can put various values. 2. Values are replaced to the same values for cells. For example, when a value of ``done`` is put to the column "B", OnEdit trigger is fired. 3. For example, when the checkboxes are ON or OFF, OnEdit trigger is fired. You can see a sample situation at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54857855/7108653).

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to ensure onEdit or other triggersn do not "miss-fire" but you could reduce the chances for this to occur

1. Prevent by design that your users apply changes in rapid succession
2. Reduce the complexity of your spreadsheet in order to make it able to recalculate as fasta as possible
3. Optimize your onEdit script to execute as fast as possible

Answer (score -1):

#### Requirement:

Enhance script to run faster to keep up with fast scanning times.

---

#### Solution:

Use event objects to your advantage, you don't need fancy `for` loops and `getValues()` for this script, it'll only slow your script down. Realistically all you need is sheet name & row/col of the edit.

```
function onEdit(event) {
  var sh = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  if (sh.getName() === 'Dolly Returns') {
    var col = event.range.getColumn();
    if (col === 2) {
      var row = event.range.getRow();
      sh.getRange(row, 1).setValue(new Date());
    }
  }
}
```

---

#### Explanation:

This script is still checking to make sure the right sheet and column are being edited, but I've removed any extra bits you didn't need. All we have/need, like I said earlier, is sheet name and row/col of the edit (so that's all I've defined).

---

#### Timings:

Okay, here's where it gets more interesting for you. I ran 10 tests with each script. Here are the results:

```
Old         New
-----       -----
0.120       0.062
0.132       0.061
0.196       0.060
0.125       0.052
0.130       0.055
0.118       0.054
0.128       0.057
0.138       0.054
0.124       0.056
0.126       0.060
```

As you can see this is a pretty big improvement, pretty much twice as fast with the same functionality as before. We're still checking for the sheet name and column and writing a date exactly like your script did.

---

#### References:

1. [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

Comment: While the "requirement" will reduce the occurrence of misfiring onEdit triggers this will not completely eliminate the occurrence of this.

Comment: I am interpreting the issue as the script is not running fast enough to keep up with the fast scanning of the user, that's why I made performance improvements. If I have misinterpreted this question then I apologise.

Comment: No need to apologize, nobody was offended. IMHO your answer will be even better if you also assumes that title correctly summarizes the issue / what he OP is looking for. If you think that it doesn't then ask for clarification.

Comment: This answer is on the right track, but it is not optimal, because it calls API methods _every_ time _any_ value in the spreadsheet is edited. The [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) lets you avoid most of those calls. See these [onEdit(e) best practices](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/155429/269219).