# Get last row with multiple users by editing spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

This is my first time, i am learning. I will try to explain my challenge. I will collect data with Odk Collect and sync with a spreadsheet. 10 users will send data to this spreadsheet at different times. I need to take the last row entered and send the data by email. My question is if "getLastRow" does the job. With 10 users I'm afraid of losing some line in sending email. Thanks in advance.

I already got the last row and the column I want. I am using the onEdit trigger. My main question is if the process is done sequentially, if 3 users send data at the same time? I lose 2 lines or getLastRow does one by one

```
function myLastRow() {
 var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
 var lr = ss.getLastRow();
 var getFiltro = ss.getRange(lr, 1).getValues();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failure of calling Google App Script onEdit function many times in a second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52811408/failure-of-calling-google-app-script-onedit-function-many-times-in-a-second)

Comment: onEdit trigger allows you to refer implicitly to the range being edited so probably you might omit the checking for the last row but use the value from the edited cell itself like `onEdit(e) { if (e.range.getColumn() == 4) { sendEmail(e.range.getValue()) ... } ... }`

Answer (score 0):

## Response:

As explained in the link referenced by @TheMaster, if many people are editing a sheet at the same time some of the edits might not be catched by the `onEdit` trigger.

## Workaround:

To be sure the emails from all rows get sent, I'd propose adding a column next to the data which will keep track of which emails have been sent. The `onEdit` would iterate through all the rows, find the ones which have not been sent, send the emails and write `Sent` in the appropriate cells. I created a small sample of how that would be like:

```
function onEditTrigger(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  // Loops through each row and send email in rows that don't have "Sent" in 4th row
  // Starts at row 2 (first row is for headers)
  for(var i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
    var row = values[i];
    var status = row[3];
    var recipient = row[0];
    var subject = row[1];
    var body = row[2];
    // Checks that the email from this row has not been sent and all data cells in the row are populated (not sure if you want this last thing, change accordingly)
    if(status != "Sent" && recipient != "" && subject != "" && body != "") {
      // In this example "recipient" is in first column, subject in second and body in third. Change accordingly
      MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body); 
      sheet.getRange(i + 1, 4).setValue("Sent");
    }
  }
}
```

Beware that you cannot use MailApp.sendEmail in a simple `onEdit`, as it happens [in any service that requires authorization](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#restrictions). So your function cannot be called `onEdit(e)`, and you have to install it by running a function that creates the trigger first, like this one:

```
function createEditTrigger() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('onEditTrigger')
      .forSpreadsheet(ss)
      .onEdit()
      .create();
}
```

I hope this is of any help to you.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I had thought of this alternative yesterday, I can even put the trigger for time. I will test your solution.

Comment: Did this work for you? Remember that, for documentation purposes, if your issue was solved you can accept the answer that provided the solution.